# How to display something before a normal function call than stop displaying afterwards?

Tags: javascript

I would like to have a loading image displayed while a normal function is running (it takes a while)

for example

```
function(){
    element.style.display = 'block';
    functionThatTakesAWhile()
    element.style.display = 'none';
}
```

my problem is that I never see the element.

-thanks.

Comment: Can you show us more of your code? Maybe the html that goes with it?

Comment: make `functionThatTakesAWhile` accept a callback with sets the elements display to none. Inside `functionThatTakesAWhile` you should know when your process has finished. When it does so execute/call the passed in callback.

Comment: is functionThatTakesAWhile() asynchronous?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give the browser a chance to render the changed display before calling `functionThatTakesAWhile`. First call `requestAnimationFrame`, which will run right before the browser repaints, and inside it, set a timeout which will run right after the browser repaints. Inside that timeout, run the expensive function:

```js
const functionThatTakesAWhile = () => {
  for (let i = 0; i < 2e9; i++);
};

console.log('script start');
// Make sure page is loaded fully first, just for the sake of this example
setTimeout(() => {
  element.style.display = 'block';
  console.log('element set to block');
  window.requestAnimationFrame(() => {
    // This callback will run just before the browser paints and displays the element
    setTimeout(() => {
      // By this time, the browser will have painted the element,
      // so you can call the expensive function
      functionThatTakesAWhile()
      element.style.display = 'none';
      console.log('element set to none');
    });
  });
}, 2000);
```

```html
content
<div id="element" style="display: none">element</div>
```

But this will still freeze the user's browser tab while the expensive function is running. It would be much better to run the expensive function in a separate thread (in a web worker), if at all possible - that way, the tab will continue to be responsive.